# Can I use a theme done for the previous version in the latest core version?

Tags: 8

Is it possible/advisable to use a Drupal 7 theme on a Drupal 8 installation?

I'm starting my first Drupal 8 project. Generally, I hit up a place like [ThemeForest](https://themeforest.net/category/cms-themes/drupal) for a theme, but their [D8 theme selection](https://themeforest.net/tags/drupal%208) is depressingly slim. Can I use a (*highly rated and actively maintained*) D7 theme instead? Is there a better place to look for professionally built D8 themes?

Comment: No, it's not possible. For one thing the template engine is now twig, so all templates would need to be rewritten

Comment: @Clive Bummer. ThemeForest has always been good to me in the past. Any alternative suggestions? Any idea why their selection is so slim?

Comment: 'Fraid not. D8 is still pretty new I guess, but other than that I'm not sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You *could* convert one if you have the time - which involves turning all tpl files to twig, updating the syntax, and making necessary changes to the template.php file (which gets renamed to template.theme). That also includes replacing any functions that don't exist anymore, and using the new D8 equivalent. Again, not too hard, but it can be if you are brand new to D8.

For smaller themes, this can take few hours to a day or two; for more involved themes, it can take longer.

Comment: Kevin, what about theme-settings.php, if I am not wrong, neither it, nor mytheme.theme are really needed, and only info.yml && libraries.yml, are really necessary in all cases.

Comment: I don't work on many themes that have a theme settings, but some still do it. Bootstrap is a unique snowflake in how it approaches it, but I have seen a few others as well. And yeah, libraries.yml, info.yml need to be provided.